# how to disable and enable tabs onloading using function

Tags: javascript

Anyone know how to disable and enable this tabs using function

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="active"><a href="#jquery">jQuery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#prototype">Prototype</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ext">Ext</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="jquery">
   jQuery is a cross-browser…
  </div>
  <div id="prototype">
   The Prototype JavaScript…
  </div>
  <div id="ext">
   Ext (X-t) is a JavaScript…
  </div>
```

and this is a script

**`$(#menu ).tabify();`**

This is I get from this website. http://unwrongest.com/projects/tabify/# .
I already use this one but its not working .

```
$("#menu").tabify({
    disabled: true
});
```

Thanks for your time guys.

Comment: Are you sure that plugin supports disabling/enabling the tabs? From its source code, that does not seem to be the case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

first check your plugins enable or disable and then try this

```
$("#menu").tabify({ 'disabled': 'true'});
```

hope this will work for you.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

HTMLElementObject.disabled=true|false.

Write it in the handler you want to disable.
like : a href="#jquery" onClick='HTMLElementObject.disabled'>jQuery

provide ids to the elements and use it to access the HTMLElementObject